# GStreamer C# UWP through WinRT/C++ doesn't work

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, gstreamer

I need to stream a live RTSP camera feed in a UWP C# application.
After trying other solutions like FFmpegInterop without any success.
They all have a lot of delay streaming the video.

We came across the gstreamer project. There is not a lot of information available on how to use it on UWP applications besides one example https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/seungha.yang/gst-uwp-example
But this seems the only option to stream live video without delay.

Unfortunately, this project is in C++. After some research we found out that you need to create a WinRT/C++ component.
We added a new WinRT/C++ reference project, added the library paths and include paths to point to the GStreamer location.

Next step is creating a GstWrapper inspired by that example and here it goes wrong:

1. cannot open #include <gst/gst.h> (even though I added the library and include paths)
2. using namespace Windows::UI::Core gives name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name (We have seen on the internet to prefix it with winrt:: but then it doesn't find UI:Core)
3. It seems that the C++ is different than the C++ that is used in that gst UWP example because other syntax issues pop up

Could someone help us out on this?